# Awk /sed extract information when a pattern match from a paragraph

Tags: sed, awk

I want to search a pattern "FROM" in paragraph that begins with CREATE VIEW and ends with ";" and save the result in a csv file. for example if I have the following file :

```
CREATE VIEW view1
AS something  
FROM table1 ,table2 as A, table3 (something FROM table4)  
FROM table5, table6
USING file1
;
CREATE VIEW view2 
FROM table1 ,table2 ,table6 ,table4
something 
something 
FROM table5 ,table7 (something FROM table4 ,table5(this is something FROM table8)
USING file2
;
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
view1;table1
view1;table2
view1;table3
view1;table4
view1;table5
view1;table6
view2;table1
view2;table2
view2;table6
view2;table4
view2;table5
view2;table7
view2;table4
view2;table5
view2;table8
```

Comment: Ok. And what have you tried so far? Do you have any code already or an idea how to solve this?

Comment: @mnille yes I have tried this code "awk -v q=" " -v OFS=";" '/^CREATE  VIEW/{split($0,a,q);v=a[3]}/FROM /{print v,$2}"  but I get only the table which is right after the word FROM

Comment: And how can we know whether you want something printed? Will table names always start with `table`? If not, how can we know that `as A` shouldn't be printed?

Comment: @terdon that's the main problem the table names don't always start with table but it ends with ","  the "AS" can be printed,  I'll remove it later

Comment: This will depend entirely on the actual text you are trying to parse. And no, your tables don't always end with `,`. You also have `FROM table8)` and `table5(` and `table6\n` and all sorts of things.  I can give you something for this example but it's anyone's guess if it will work on your actual table names.

Comment: So you want to determine on what tables each view depends? This way that's not a trivial task: you have to take in account much of the (SQL) syntax, and actually need to build a pretty complicated parser -- not a job for the shell. I guess there are much easier ways to solve the (principal) problem.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: forgot the first line (so I changed L++ into ++L) :
Edit2: fixed regexp to not "glob" the whole parenthesis until the last FROM

We may be able to use "creatively" the field separations to get rid of what we don't want to keep and just retrieve table names :

```
$ LC_ALL="C" awk -v csvsep=';' -v separators='FROM *| *, *| +as[^,]*| *[(][^()]*FROM *| *[)] *'  '
   /CREATE VIEW/ { name=$NF }
   /FROM / { nb=split($0,tables,separators);
             for(i=1;i<=nb;i++) {
               (tables[i]~/[A-Za-z]/) ? line[++L]=name csvsep tables[i] : rem="Otherwise nothing to add" }
           }
   END  { for(i=1;i<=L;i++) { print line[i] } }'
```

Then we feed it:

```
CREATE VIEW view1
AS something
FROM table1 ,table2 as A, table3 (something FROM table4)
FROM table5, table6
USING file1
;
CREATE VIEW view2
FROM table1 ,table2 ,table6 ,table4
something
something
FROM table5 ,table7 (something FROM table4 ,table5(this is something FROM table8)
USING file2
;
```

And it gives the expected:

```
view1;table1
view1;table2
view1;table3
view1;table4
view1;table5
view1;table6
view2;table1
view2;table2
view2;table6
view2;table4
view2;table5
view2;table7
view2;table4
view2;table5
view2;table8
```

Note: we just process lines containing "FROM" so if you have creative FROM lines (on multiple lines...) it will not work without some more magic.

Comment: fixed it (my first regexp was too greedy inside parenthesis, and globbed everything until the last "FROM"). Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](http://www.nongnu.org/txr) solution:

```
@(define word (w))@{w /[^,\s()]+/}@(end)
@(collect)
@  (cases)
CREATE VIEW @view@/ /
@  (or)
CREATE VIEW @view
@  (end)
@  (collect)
@    (coll :vars (table))@\
       FROM @(word first-tbl)@\
       @(coll :vars (rest-tbl) :gap 0)@\
         @/\s*,\s*/@(word rest-tbl)@\
         @(maybe) as @(word something)@(end)@\
       @(end)@\
       @(merge table first-tbl rest-tbl)@\
     @(end)
@  (until)
CREATE@(skip)
@  (end)
@  (flatten table)
@(end)
@(output)
@  (repeat)
@    (repeat)
@view;@table
@    (end)
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr extract.txr data
view1;table1
view1;table2
view1;table3
view1;table4
view1;table5
view1;table6
view2;table1
view2;table2
view2;table6
view2;table4
view2;table5
view2;table7
view2;table4
view2;table5
view2;table8
```

Note that if `as` occurs as `AS`, that has to be worked into the code; for instance using `@/[Aa][Ss]/`.